# Fast Interactive force-directed graph layout engine

Tags: layout, graph, visualization, interactive

I need a framework/library which will enable me to develop a realtime interactive graph simulation. The user must be able to dynamically add nodes and edges. I have found [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) and its force directed layout and I really like it. But it is not fully thread-safe, and doesn't perform all that well -- maybe it has problems with big graphs?

Are there some decent alternatives? I know about [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/), but I have no desire to learn ActionScript and would rather stick with c++/java/c#.

Comment: How big of graph are you talking about?  Prefuse actually scales fairly well.

Comment: I've created graph with approx. 1500 nodes and it became really slow.

Comment: How do you expect from your users to create a graph of size 1500 with mouse and keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

[yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/) is a good commercial library (Java, C#, ActionScript, Javascript versions available) for interactive graph visualization, that supports wide range of layouts, and has no problems showing very big graphs. You can test its capabilities quickly by trying [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html), which is based on yFiles.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old but still let me introduce another commercial option for C#. [GraphX for .NET PRO](http://graphx.pro) is capable of rendering thousands of vertices and edges simultaneously and supports variety of force-directed layouts. There is also [free open-source version](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX) which is less performant but supports easy styling features.